# Application runs without any user interaction

Tags: java, android, android-button

Displaying two random numbers and counting scores for odd and even turns. When one of it reaches to 100, the application stops.

This is my code..

```
public class Board_Play1 extends Activity {

int d=0,a=0,b=0,turn=2;
Random random = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.board_play1);
    EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));  
    p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
    p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));

    while(a!=100 && b!=100)
    {
        if(turn%2==0)
        {
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
                    EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));

                }
            }); 
        }
        else
        {

            d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
            diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));
        }

    if(turn%2==0)
            a+=d;
        else
            b+=d;

    if(a>100)
        a-=d;
    if(b>100)
        b-=d;


        p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
        p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
        turn++;
    }
    a=0;b=0;

}


}
```

When I run this.. It goes like.. everything is completed. All the time `p2` editText gets 100 and `p1` will have some number less than 100 and `diceno` has a value `100-p1`.

But well that's not the main question I want to ask. It is that I added Buttons and `onClickListener` methods that run only when user clicks on that particular button. But nothing such is happening. As soon as I open the app it gets their max. values and user got nothing to do.

Why is it being that way? Help what to do so that I start with values `0` in both `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but you probably should not put the initialization for your button inside the while loop

Comment: You have problem in your logic

Comment: @Raghunandan what's wrong?

Comment: @vinaykumar Log values in your while and if conditions and check what is happening

Comment: @Jeeter That did not help :(

Comment: @Raghunandan I went through LogCats I mostly did not understand what's in there. Here are they http://ideone.com/E08oIz . Can you please look into them..

Comment: @vinaykumari said log the values like `Log.i("value of a is",""+a);` Similarly log the values of your editext and the values that you calculate. Run the app and you will see the values in logcat. Check what is happening and fix the same. By the way pls don't post links to external source. Not many will look at the same

Comment: As Raghunandan said, you have problem in your *coding* logic. That said, your logic might be fine, but implemented wrongly in coding. One thing, if you want your app to run manually, remove `while-loop`. Then, you just need to initialize `OnClickListener` once, and put most of your code there.

Comment: Start with a basic android tutorial. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#Create

Comment: @Raghunandan I checked them using Log values. It shows never it is entering setOnClickListener() method!

Comment: @Raghunandan turn is being incremented by 1 every time while loop is repeated. So `turn%2==0` is not always true

Comment: @vinaykumar Log the value of turn everytime the loops runs. Good luck

Comment: @vinaykumar specify what you want clearly. Your title says one and the accepted answer does another

Comment: @vinaykumar A handler can be used to delay. i already commented. this is my last comment as this is leading to discussion. i don't think you have enough repo to chat either. So new problem post a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I changed your code

```
public class Board_Play1 extends Activity {

int d=0,a=0,b=0,turn=2;
Random random = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.board_play1);
EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));  
p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
               diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));

                if(turn%2==0)
                        a+=d;
                    else
                        b+=d;

                if(a>100)
                    a-=d;
                if(b>100)
                    b-=d;


                    p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                    p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
                    turn++;
            }


        }); 
 }


}
```

**Update :** I will add one more method to calculateDiceno. I think this will helps you

```
public class Board_Play1 extends Activity {

int d=0,a=0,b=0,turn=2;
Random random = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.board_play1);
        EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));  
        p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
        p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
        EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // This is user Turn
                        d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
                        diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));
                        calculateDiceno();

                        //This is Application Trun. You may add some delay with progress bar

                        d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
                        diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));
                        calculateDiceno();


                    }

        }); 


 }

    private void calculateDiceno(){
           if(turn%2==0)
                a+=d;
            else
                b+=d;

        if(a>100)
            a-=d;
        if(b>100)
            b-=d;


            p1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
            p2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
            turn++;
        }


}
```

**Update 2:** Don't use sleep(). Use Handler for some delay.

```
//This is Application Trun. You may add some delay with progress bar
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
          //This will execute after 3 sec
          d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
      diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));
      calculateDiceno();
    }
}, 3000);  // 3000 means set 3 sec delay.
```

Comment: I want t generate input in such a way that one input is given by user and next will be generated automatically..

Comment: how is that repeating? Is it that onCreate() method keeps on repeating while an application is running?

Comment: @vinaykumar how can you come to conclusion onCreate is repeating? Do you know the activity lifecycle? The repeating is bcoz of the while loop. Use a handler to create a delay of 1second you will see the values changing on button click

Comment: @vinaykumar onCreate is called once during the lifecycle of the activity untill its destroyed and recreated

Comment: @vinaykumar then there is no repeatition and that is not what you want is it? and you accepted the answer?

Comment: @vinaykumar Your wrong onCreate not repeating. Check button onClick ()  whenever users clicks the button we are generate numbers for users  and then again we are generate number for application. So its looks like repeating.

Comment: @Raghunandan No but this is repeating. So did I thought that onCreate() could repeat and so did I asked that. With these codes I can click the button multiple times where `onClickListener()` is defined only once.

Comment: @Raghunandan I think he try to ask how is repeating ? never told it is not repeated.

Comment: @vinaykumar Once your set the click listener to button that will works   until the activity is finish. no need to add again and again. so it will work. and no need to recreate button and set event listener each time. Instead of that I have separate your logic into calculatedDiceno and called it in click listener. I hope you understand now.

Comment: @PrakashM the title says **Application runs without any user interaction**. I don't know what he wants and why is button needed if he wants no user interaction. But the title says so

Comment: @Raghunandan yes,you are right, but he thinks to ask He added the button click listener but its not working, application never waits to user's click. That is because of he did logic error. refer his question.

Comment: @Raghunandan I need user to click on a button. And the code I have written doesn't allow user to click but instead runs to an end point. So I named the problem that Application is running without user interaction

Comment: @vinaykumar and what is your requirement?? That is not clear at all. You still seem to have logic errors

Comment: @PrakashM either the title is misleading or this is a wrong answer

Comment: @PrakashM I added sleep() method to have some delay time between user's turn and application turn. But on running editText gets updated only after application's turn. Why is it so?

Comment: @vinaykumar sleep on a ui thread is very wrong. Should not keep the ui thread waiting. Will lead to ANR.

Comment: @Raghunandan what else can I use to get delay